# Tabela zebrada em HTML com Ext JS

Tags: css, html, extjs, tabela-zebrada

Preciso fazer uma tabela zebrada na funcionalidade Xtemplate do ExTJS 4.1.2 onde possuo dois laços de repetição for. Implementei um HTML básico, mas alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Como você está exibindo estas informações? Esta usando um grid, uma table ou divs?

Comment: estou usando divs

Comment: no caso essa pergunta não precisaria estar marcada como ExtJS, já que vc está usando o Xtemplate pra exibir HTML e o problema está na geração desse html...

Comment: Concordo com o @Guilherme, a menos que o autor queira uma solução utilizando recursos do ExtJS. Se for esse o caso, edite sua pergunta para podermos ajudá-lo melhor.

Answer (score 5):

Segundo [essa página](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells), linhas pares de um *grid* possuem a classe CSS `x-grid-row-alt`. Assim, basta você definir no seu CSS cores diferentes para as classes `x-grid-row` e `x-grid-row-alt`:

```css
x-grid-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    color: #000; 
} 

.x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: No meu caso nao estou utilizando css no ExTJS e sim css numa propriedade que utiliza html no caso o Xtemplate. e Reafirmando o que o Guilherme falo.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que haja maneiras mais elegantes, usando uma table, ou um grid, mas no caso de estar gerando a lista atravez de um for/foreach, você pode

```php
    for ($i=0;$row[$i];$i++){
        if ($i %  2  !=  0){//estou apenas verificando se é uma div par
            echo"<div class='dark'> ... <\div>";
        }esle{
            echo"<div class='light'> ... <\div>";
        }  
    }
```

E na folha de estilos .css

```css
.dark { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    color: #000; 
} 

.light { 
    background-color: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```